# remove digits from the output jsoup

Tags: java, substring, jsoup, stringbuilder, println

I've made this simple code to extract the ID of some players... but, don't need the whole output i need the last 4 digits, this is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class ListLinks {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
            Document doc;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/teams/bal/roster/").get();

                Elements urls = doc.select("a[data-pid]");
                for (Element url : urls) {   


                    System.out.println(url.attr("data-pid"));

                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ListLinks.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the output

```
mlb.p.8117
mlb.p.9699
etc...
```

So I need to remove the the first 6 digits from the output.. Please tell me how... This is my first time programming!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Element class of JSoup has a method called id() to return the id of an Element: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#id()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I need to remove the the first 6 digits from the output..

I assume that by digit you actually mean character. Anyway since you already know how many characters you want to remove from start you can use `substring` method and pass index of character from which new string can be created like

```
System.out.println(url.attr("data-pid").substring(6));
```

But this answer is based on assumption that you know index of character from which you want to substring. If you want to make your code little safer and always remove any characters that are placed before last `.` you can use something like

```
System.out.println(url.attr("data-pid").replaceAll(".*[.]",""));
```

You can also use other techniques like ones shown in [@VoodooCoder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4802890/voodoocoder) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29732234/1393766)

Comment: This is not safe at all because if the provider modify the data-pid string of a single character he need necessarily to modify the code. But it works :D

Comment: @VoodooCoder "*if the provider modify the data-pid string of a single character he need to modify the code.*" that is the problem of any approach we use. Provider may modify data in a way that it can look like `mlb.p.81.17` which prevents us from using `split("[.]")` or `mlb.p.8117.321` which prevents us from use `lastIndexOf(".")`. There is no 100% correct solution here.

Comment: Sure, you are right but i prefer don't change the code every time the provider modifies the string in this way: `mlb.p.8117` -> `mXXlb.p.8117` or `mlb.p.8117` -> `mlb.pXX.8117`

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in different ways:

```
String pid = url.attr("data-pid");
```

**- Splitting the string and retrieving the last group of chars (second in this case because it starts from 0):**

```
String result = pid.split("\\.")[2];
```

*Usefull when you need to store or do something with the other groups.

You must be sure that the string contains dot symbol*

**- Searching the last occurence position of dot symbol and substring from its index to the end of the string:**

```
String result = pid.substring(pid.lastIndexOf(".")+1);
```

*Usefull if you need only the last group of chars.

You must be sure that the string contains dot symbol*

**- Using a regex:**

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("-?\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(pid);
String result = null;
while (m.find()) {
    result = m.group();
}
```

*The safest way from my point of view.*